# Is a pointer allowed to change value in single inheritance?

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, language-lawyer, multiple-inheritance

I know that with multiple inheritance the value of a pointer is allowed to change. But is that the case with single inheritance too? Or with POD types for that matter?

You probably know the classic example:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
struct Base1 { virtual void f1() {} };
struct Base2 { virtual void f2() {} };
struct Derived : public Base1, public Base2 { virtual void g() {} };
int main() {
    Derived d{};
    auto *pd = &d;
    auto pb1 = (Base1*)pd;
    auto pb2 = (Base2*)pd;
    cout << pd << "\n"; // say, 0x1000
    cout << pb1 << "\n"; // say, 0x1000
    cout << pb2 << "\n"; // say, 0x1008 !!!
}
```

So far so good and that is good old compiler practice. The objects are layed out in a way that the "root" of `Base2` has an offset to `Derived` which can be printed when looking at the actual pointer value. This not a problem when refraining from doing `void*` and `reinterpret_cast`s.

And as far as I know in practice this occurs only with multiple inheritance.

But my question: What does the standard say about "pointer changing values during cast"? Can this happen *only* with multiple inheritance or can that also happen with single inheritance, or casting PODs?

Comment: A simple counterexample for non-POD types: `struct Base1 { int x; }; struct Derived : Base1 { virtual void f(){} };`.

Comment: @RaymondChen: It might be good to state for which compiler that's a counterexample.

Comment: It's a counterexample in compilers which put the vtable at the start of the object. Most compilers do this because it is required by many ABIs. (The one exception I know about is that certain versions of Borland C++ put the vtable at the end of the object.)

Answer (score 4):

If the type is standard-layout, then a pointer to the containing struct at any level of inheritance is equal to a pointer to the first element.  By transitivity, the pointers to all levels of inheritance are also the same -- and the Standard goes ahead and also makes this guarantee in the odd case when no non-static data members exist.

(Note that to be standard-layout, a type can introduce data members at only one level in the inheritance diagram -- further subclasses can add functions and remain standard layout, but cannot add more data).

If the type is not standard-layout, then no guarantees are made and you must use `static_cast`, not `reinterpret_cast` (nor reinterpret_cast equivalents such as multiple static_cast with `void*` as an intermediate) to properly include any offset.

All POD types are of course standard-layout, PODness requires both standard-layout and triviality.

The exact rule I'm explaining is found in section 9.2:

> If a standard-layout class object has any non-static data members, its address is the same as the address of its first non-static data member. Otherwise, its address is the same as the address of its first base class subobject (if any).
>
> [ Note: There might therefore be unnamed padding within a standard-layout struct object, but not at its beginning, as necessary to achieve appropriate alignment. — end note ]
>
> [ Note: The object and its first subobject are pointer-interconvertible. — end note ]

The rule that explicitly states that odd layouts are possible for types which are non standard-layout is in section 10:

> The order in which the base class subobjects are allocated in the most derived object is unspecified.

Comment: Just to be sure: `class Base { int i; }; class Derived : public Base { int j; };`  do *not* have standard layout (both add non-static data members). And hence their pointers can have different values. Right?

Comment: @towi: correct on both points, although I've never seen a compiler that actually uses that permission and does align such a simple case at a nonzero offset

Answer (score 3):

> Is a pointer allowed to change value in single inheritance?

I am not able to find anything in the standard that would prevent an implementation from doing that.

I found the following in the C++11 standard that are related to conversion of pointers between pointers to base classes and derived classes:

> **4.10 Pointer conversion**
>
> 3 A prvalue of type “pointer to *cv* `D`”, where `D` is a class type, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to *cv* `B`”, where `B` is a base class (Clause 10) of `D`. If `B` is an inaccessible (Clause 11) or ambiguous (10.2) base class of `D`, a program that necessitates this conversion is ill-formed. The result of the conversion is a pointer to the base class subobject of the derived class object. The null pointer value is converted to the null pointer value of the destination type.

and

> **5.2.9 Static cast**
>
> 2 An lvalue of type “*cv1* `B`,” where `B` is a class type, can be cast to type “reference to *cv2* `D`,” where `D` is a class derived (Clause 10) from `B`, if a valid standard conversion from “pointer to D” to “pointer to B” exists (4.10), *cv2* is the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, *cv1*, and `B` is neither a virtual base class of `D` nor a base class of a virtual base class of `D`. The result has type “*cv2* `D`.” An xvalue of type “*cv1* `B`” may be cast to type “rvalue reference to *cv2* `D`” with the same constraints as for an lvalue of type “*cv1* `B`.” If the object of type “*cv1* `B`” is actually a subobject of an object of type `D`, the result refers to the enclosing object of type `D`. Otherwise, the result of the cast is undefined. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> struct B { };
> struct D : public B { };
> D d;
> B &br = d;
> static_cast<D&>(br); // produces lvalue to the original d object
> ```
>
> —*end example* ]

---

Given

```
class B { ... };
class D : public B { ... };
```

An implementation is free to choose the following layout:

```
+------------------+
|  D members       |
+------------------+
|  B members       |
+------------------+
```

as long as it does the right thing when converting pointers and references.

In such an implementation,

```
D d;
D* dptr = &d;
B* bptr = &d;
```

The values of `dptr` and `bptr` are going to be different.

Comment: Thanks. I admit that I am not able to read 5.2.9 in a way that I can tell that your example is covered by it. I have to believe you that your example fits that paragraph. I assume you are sure...

Comment: @towi, 5.2.9 relies on 4.10. *if a valid standard conversion from “pointer to D” to “pointer to B” exists (4.10)* As long as a `D*` pointer can be converted to `B*`, 5.2.9 is well defined.

Comment: This answer is half-wrong.  It doesn't address POD, which the question asked about, or standard-layout, which *does* impose different requirements.  And "I am not able to find anything in the Standard" is a lame excuse when the exact text and location of a very relevant rule are given by an older answer.

Comment: Even the statements you make associated with your example may be outright non-conformant, depending on what the `...` hides.

Comment: @BenVoigt, please elaborate.